# Handling errors while working with code snippets

Tags: python, exception, python-interactive

I am running a bunch of code all at once in python by copying it from my editor and pasting it into python.  This code includes nested for loops.  I am doing some web scraping and the program quits at different times.  I suspect that this is because it doesn't have time to load.  I get the following error (once again - the program scrapes different amounts of text each time):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 35, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

First, what does `line 35` refer to?  Is this the place in the relevant inner for-loop?

Second, I think that the error might be caused by a line of code using selenium like this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("button")[j-1].click()
```

In this case, how can handle this error?  What is some example code with either explicit waits or exception handling that would address the issue?

Comment: Normally, for anything more than very small snippets, you would save your Python script into a file and then run it through the `python` command line command. This will be far more sustainable than pasting into a Python REPL. The benefit, in your current situation, is that the line number reported by Python will refer to an actual line number in your file.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using the `python` method vs. `execfile(filename)` in the Python REPL?

Comment: I suppose you could use `execfile()`, that would work equally well.

Comment: It was the 35th line pasted. Pasting a script can fail if one defined function calls another later in the posted file. But you get an error about a name not being defined. Why not just write the script to a file and test that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try your code and catch an IndexError exception like this:

```
try:
    # your code here
except IndexError:
    # handle the error here
```

An IndexError happens when you try to access an index of a list that does not exist. For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(a[10])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It's difficult to say how you should handle the error without more detail.

Answer (score 2):

It means that `[j-1]` doesn't exist for a given value of `j`, possibly if `j-1` exceeds the max number of elements in the list

Comment: Not sure who down voted, but this is a good explanation of the error.

Answer (score 1):

When working with code snippets, it's convenient to have them open in a text editor and either

- only copy-paste into a console the part you're currently working on so that all the relevant variables are in the local namespace that you can explore from the console, or
- copy-paste a moderate-to-large chunk as a whole while having enabled automatic post-mortem debugger calling, e.g. with [Automatically start the debugger on an exception Activestate recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65287-automatically-start-the-debugger-on-an-exception/) or [IPython's %pdb magic](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-pdb), or
- run a script as a whole under debugger e.g with [`-m pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html?highlight=pdb), [IPython's %run](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) or by using [an IDE](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments).